# Fill multiple rows in google spreadsheet via google script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, arduino

I am currently working on a semester project for my university in which we want to log data from an Arduino to a Google Sheet.

I was following the numerous tutorials and examples that I could find on Google and it worked so far really, really well. My Arduino is able to upload data to said spreadsheet.

Unfortunately all those examples always only deal with one row to be filled. For our project we would like to fill 2 or 3 lines simultaneously.

I will shortly show what I have done so far and maybe you can help me solve my (probably easy) problem.

- I created a google spreadsheet in which I want to log my data
- I used the script from a tutorial that should fill one row.
- By typing the following line in my browser
  `https://script.google.com/macros/s/<gscript id>/exec?tempData=datahere`
  I am now able to fill row one with my data in enter in the end of the url.

But how do I progress now, when I want to fill two or three rows of the table? I say that the author of the code already implemented an option to fill the third row, yet I can't find out what to input in my url then to fill it with data.

All my attempts to write something like

```
https://script.google.com/macros/s/<gscript id>/exec?tempData=datahere&tempData1=value2
```

just ended in writing

```
datahere&tempData1=value2
```

in my first row, not filling `datahere` into the first and `value2` in to the second row.

How can I provide and write multiple rows of data?

The code in this script is:

```
/*
GET request query:
https://script.google.com/macros/s/<gscript id>/exec?tempData=data_here
*/
/* Using spreadsheet API */
function doGet(e) { 
    Logger.log( JSON.stringify(e) );  // view parameters
    var result = 'Ok'; // assume success

    if (e.parameter == undefined) {
        result = 'No Parameters';
    }
    else {
        var id = '<ssheet id>'; // Spreadsheet ID
        var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById(id).getActiveSheet();
        var newRow = sheet.getLastRow() + 1;
        var rowData = [];
        //var waktu = new Date();
        rowData[0] = new Date(); // Timestamp in column A
        for (var param in e.parameter) {
            Logger.log('In for loop, param='+param);
            var value = stripQuotes(e.parameter[param]);
            //Logger.log(param + ':' + e.parameter[param]);
            switch (param) {
                case 'tempData': //Parameter
                    rowData[1] = value; //Value in column B
                    break;
                case 'tempData1':
                    rowData[2] = value; //Value in column C
                    break;
                default:
                    result = "unsupported parameter";
            }
        }
        Logger.log(JSON.stringify(rowData));

        // Write new row below
        var newRange = sheet.getRange(newRow, 1, 1, rowData.length);
        newRange.setValues([rowData]);
    }
    // Return result of operation
    return ContentService.createTextOutput(result);
}

/**
 * Remove leading and trailing single or double quotes
 */
function stripQuotes( value ) {
    return value.replace(/^["']|['"]$/g, "");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest the following:

1. Create a 2d array of your data you wish to write to the spreadsheet. If your client on Arduino were using JavaScript this might look like :

   ```
   var data = [
     ["row1value1", "row1value2"],
     ["row2value1", "row2value2"]
   ];
   ```
2. Convert this to JSON, again in JavaScript this might look like:

   ```
   var json = JSON.stringify(data);
   ```

   This gives you a string representation of your array.
3. Now make your request using this data. I would suggest you should look at using `doPost` instead of `doGet`, as you are sending data to the spreadsheet that updates state. However, for the purposes of getting something working, your URL would look like:

   ```
   https://script.google.com/<.....>/exec?myarray=<stringified JSON>
   ```
4. In Apps Script, in your `doGet` (again, consider using `doPost` instead), you could then use:

   ```
   // Get the JSON representation of the array:
   var json = e.parameter.myarray;
   // Convert back to 2d array
   var data = JSON.parse(json);
   ```
5. Now you can write this to a `Range` in Sheets using `setValues`, e.g. assuming a rectangular 2d array:

   ```
   sheet.getRange(1, 1, data.length, data[0].length).setValues(data);
   ```

Hope this helps